# Why a stateful react component still acts as a pure function?

Tags: reactjs

According to React's doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only

> React is pretty flexible but it has a single strict rule:
>
> **All React components must act like pure functions with respect to their props.**
>
> Of course, application UIs are dynamic and change over time. In the next section, we will introduce a new concept of “state”. State allows React components to change their output over time in response to user actions, network responses, and anything else, without violating this rule.

I just don't understand how can something with internal state not violate the ''pure function'' rule? If the output of a component changes over time, doesn't it mean that it is not always the same with the same input of ''props''?

Comment: I guess they're putting more importance on *"because they do not attempt to change their inputs"*, and not depending on *external* state.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for quick reply. What you said is correct in terms of React, but these two points don't make something a pure function. A pure function should always give the same output as long as the input is the same, e.g. an accumulator with an internal counter is not a pure function.